# Qt Creator - Build duration longer on Windows

Tags: linux, windows, qt

I'm developing an application with Qt on Qt Creator and have been transferring and moving a project and its corresponding files from Windows to Linux, and vice versa. I've been noticing that on Linux the build is a lot faster compared to when I'm building the application on Windows. Is this normal? And if not, how can I fix it?

Normally a build on my Linux machine will take a few seconds, and on Windows it takes a long time and sometimes to the point that I just stop building.

Comment: It's impossible to say if this is expected without seeing your build setup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not unnormal. Compilation typically creates lots of comparatively small files, and that's not where Windows file systems shine. In any case, double-check virus scanner settings, you might not want your temporary files scanned repeatedly.